# Can I handle BeanCreationException in spring?

Tags: spring

Spring will throw BeanCreationException if there's some problem when creating a bean. If there's a way to do some thing when this exception is thrown, say, halt the process?

Comment: No. It is fatal and the start of your application will be stopped.

Comment: Why do you want to handle the error? What is your use case?